# Use Vault to manage Kubernetes secrets

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, vault

We are using Kubernetes on Google Kubernetes Engine - we currently have secrets added manually with the kubectl secret CLI.

To make the secrets management more secure and easier across the team, we installed a [Hashicorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) instance on a separate cluster.

What is the way to connect a Vault k/v store to the Kubernetes secrets ?

I'm looking for something like this

```
  volumes:
    - name: commonsecrets
      secret:
        source: vault
        secretName: commonsecrets
        items:
        - key: SOME_API_KEY
          path: apikey.txt
        - key: SOME_CERTIFICATE
          path: certificate.pub
```

Answer (score 0):

**First thing that needs to be said clearly:** kubernetes `Secret` API object/resource != **Hashicorp Vault** secrets, that you can use with **kubernetes**. If you use first = you don't youse the latter.

So basically there is no way to manage Kubernetes [`Secrets`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) by Hashicorp Vault. Instead of using kubernetes `Secret` object to store sensitive data, consumed by your `Pods` you use for that purpose **Hahicorp Vault**. As vault secrets can be injected directly into `Pods`, you don't need to additionally mount them as volumes as in your example.

If you want to integrate **Hashicorp Vault** instance, installed on a separate cluster, the whole setup is described [here](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/kubernetes-external-vault).

If you want to deploy an app with hard-coded external Vault address, the official [Hashicorp Vault documentation](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/kubernetes-external-vault#deploy-application-with-hard-coded-vault-address) also explains how to do that:

> The most direct way for a pod within the cluster to address Vault is
> with a hard-coded network address defined within the application code
> or provided as an environment variable. We've created and published a
> web application that you will deploy with the Vault address overriden.
>
> First, create a Kubernetes service account for the pods to use to
> authenticate.
>
> ```
> ServiceAccount metadata:   name: internal-app EOF
> ```
>
> Create a deployment with this web application that sets the
> `VAULT_ADDR` to `EXTERNAL_VAULT_ADDR`.
>
> ```
> --- 
> apiVersion: apps/v1 
> kind: Deployment 
> metadata:   
>   name: devwebapp
>   labels:
>     app: devwebapp 
> spec:   
>   replicas: 1  
>   selector:
>     matchLabels:
>       app: devwebapp   template:
>     metadata:
>       labels:
>         app: devwebapp
>     spec:
>       serviceAccountName: internal-app
>       containers:
>       - name: app
>         image: burtlo/devwebapp-ruby:k8s
>         imagePullPolicy: Always
>         env:
>         - name: VAULT_ADDR
>           value: "http://$EXTERNAL_VAULT_ADDR:8200" EOF
> ```
>
> The web application, targeting the external Vault, is deployed as a
> pod within the default namespace.
>
> Get all the pods within the default namespace.
>
> ```
> STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE devwebapp-68cc55948b-w9745   1/1     Running 
> 0          4m
> ```
>
> Wait until the `devwebapp` pod reports that is running and ready
> (`1/1`).
>
> Request content served at `localhost:8080` from within the `devwebapp`
> pod.
>
> ```
>     $(kubectl get pod -l app=devwebapp -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}") \
>     -- curl -s localhost:8080 ; echo
> ```
>
> The result displays the secret is defined at the path
> `secret/data/devwebapp/config`.
>
> ```
>    {"password"=>"salsa", "username"=>"giraffe"}
> ```
>
> The web application authenticates with the external Vault server using
> the root token and returns the secret defined at the path
> `secret/data/devwebapp/config`. This hard-coded approach is an
> effective solution if the address to the Vault server does not change.

It's just one example among at least a few available approaches. Alternatively you may want to [Deploy service and endpoints to address an external Vault](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/kubernetes-external-vault#deploy-service-and-endpoints-to-address-an-external-vault) or [Install the Vault Helm chart configured to address an external Vault](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/kubernetes-external-vault#install-the-vault-helm-chart-configured-to-address-an-external-vault). As you can read in documentation:

> The Vault Helm chart can deploy only the Vault Agent Injector service
> configured to target an external Vault. The injector service enables
> the authentication and secret retrieval for the applications, by
> adding Vault Agent containers as they are written to the pod
> automatically when a deployment includes specific annotations.

You may also want to take a look at the following articles:

[Managing Secrets in Kubernetes with Vault by HashiCorp](https://blog.kubernauts.io/managing-secrets-in-kubernetes-with-vault-by-hashicorp-f0db45cc208a)

[Injecting Vault Secrets Into Kubernetes Pods via a Sidecar](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/injecting-vault-secrets-into-kubernetes-pods-via-a-sidecar/)

[Injecting Secrets into Kubernetes Pods via Vault Helm Sidecar](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/kubernetes-sidecar?in=vault/kubernetes)

And many more [related with using Hashicorp Vault with Kubernetes](https://learn.hashicorp.com/collections/vault/kubernetes).